# Are the hyperreal numbers densely ordered?

Tags: set-theory

Using the construction mentioned [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719131/ultrapower-and-hyperreals) are the hyperreals densely ordered? If not, is there a construction in which they are?

This should be a rather straightforward question, but my brain just hasn't been working properly as of late and there are still a fair number of topics in set theory that are unclear to me. It looks like it should be an application of Łoś's theorem?

Comment: What happens if you try to look at ${x+y}\over2$ as a number strictly between $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct proof is straightforward.

Let $[x]_\mathscr{U}$ and $[y]_\mathscr{U}$ be hyperreals, where $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and assume that $[x]_\mathscr{U}<[y]_\mathscr{U}$. Then $U=\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n<y_n\}\in\mathscr{U}$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $z_n=\frac12(x_n+y_n)$; then

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n<z_n<y_n\}\supseteq U\in\mathscr{U}\;,$$

so $[x]_\mathscr{U}<[z]_\mathscr{U}<[y]_\mathscr{U}$.

Answer (score 0):

They are, for example by the transfer principle.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to write this in such a way that it is valid. For instance:

The transfer principle appears to lead to contradictions if it is not handled correctly. For example, since the hyperreal numbers form a non-Archimedean ordered field and the reals form an Archimedean ordered field, the property of being Archimedean ("every positive real is larger than 1/n for some positive integer n") seems at first sight not to satisfy the transfer principle.

Comment: The statement "every positive hyperreal is larger than 1/n for some positive integer n" is false; however the correct interpretation is "every positive hyperreal is larger than 1/n for some positive hyperinteger n". In other words, the hyperreals appear to be archimedean to an internal observer living in the non-standard universe, but appear to be non-archimedean to an external observer outside the universe.

Comment: Transfer principle applies only to first-order statements @vasshu and the integers are not definable in first-order theory of real closed fields